Which external factors are affecting the price of quality steel in North America?
With rumors of war in recent years, the price of good steel is important to all global powers. Just by going to the hardware store month to month, I have noticed that the price of even sheet steel has been increasing dramatically over the past few years.
US Steel (NYSE ticker symbol X) is one of the only producers of steel remaining in North America. They were almost bought by a Japanese company a few months ago -- Nippon Steel -- but the deal was nixed by The US Federal Government.
Which companies benefit from scarcity of steel with higher prices right now? Which countries would benefit from The USA having difficulty acquiring good steel -- for engineering applications or otherwise? While other countries may produce very nice steel, they do not care about our bridges, infrastructure, and war machines like we do.

This is not the forum for your type of question since it is not about design but the economy of steel.

@StainlessSteelRat, are you trying to "rat" me out? I actually tagged the post with #engineering-economics, which is a legitimate tag.

Regardless of the irony of my handle and your question, it's about the economics of steel and the US.  Very little about engineering design.  As in an engineering problem to solve.  This would have more luck on an economics or US foreign policy forum.  JMO

Nucor is the big steel maker now

I see that X's market cap is about 25% that of Nucor now -- they've come a long way. It used to be the other way around, the way I remember it, and that wasn't as long ago as you might think. I wonder what happened. I was just being facetious, rat, but your second argument is fairer. Still, I fail to grok why people get so bent out of shape on forums about that sort of thing. I ought not to bother.

This is a Q&A site. Where OP has a specific problem they wish to solve with hopefully a specific answer or answers. You have specific knowledge and are seeking a discussion, so no specific answer. Comments are just that, comments.
